# an error is displayed The view images.views.image_create didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

Code:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect 
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required   
    from django.contrib import messages
    from .forms import ImageCreateForm
    
    @login_required    
    def image_create(request):   
      if request.method == 'POST':
        # форма отправлена
        form = ImageCreateForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
          # данные в форме валидны
          cd = form.cleaned_data
          new_image = form.save(commit=False)
          # назначить текущего пользователя элемент
          new_image.user = request.user
          new_image.save()
          messages.success(request,'Image added successfully')
          # перенаправить к представлению детальной
          # информации о только что созданном элементе
          return redirect(new_image.get_absolute_url())
        else:
          # скомпоновать форму с данными,
          # предоставленными букмарклетом методом GET
          form = ImageCreateForm(data=request.GET)
        return render(request,'images/image/create.html',{'section': 'images','form': form})
```

If I write code from the phone and run it on `Termux`.

I tried to check the code, but didn't find anything.

Comment: on case of a GET request the view returns nothing